How can i display multiple tables on SSRS based on parameters
i have to create a transaction table that will show the results of Multiple tables such as successful transaction, Disputed, failed and cancelled all at the same time.
expected reults
i have tried to use iif statements and checkbox but it does not work

You'll need to add much more info. Edit your question to show a sample (as text) of your data. Explain how it is stored in your database, is it in separate database tables? What parameters will the user select? What will the final output look like?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
